# Converting XDocument to JSON with XHTML node using JSON.NET

Tags: json, xhtml, json.net

Is there a simpler way to do this? I am sincerely concerned that this LinqPad doodle might be too verbose:

```
var xml = @"
<root attr1=""attribute one"" attr2=""attribute two"">
    <title>this is the root</title>
    <xhtml>
        <div id=""wrapper"">
            <p style=""first""><em>hello</em> world!</p>
        </div>
    </xhtml>
</root>
";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

Func<XNode, string> getXhtml = node =>
{
    var s = string.Empty;
    StringWriter wr = null;
    try
    {
        wr = new StringWriter();
        using(var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(wr))
        {
            jsonWriter.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
            new JsonSerializer().Serialize(jsonWriter, node.ToString());
        }
        s = wr.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(wr != null) wr.Dispose();
    }
    return s;
};

var escaped_xhtml = getXhtml(xDoc.Root.Element("xhtml").Element("div"));
escaped_xhtml.Dump("escaped xhtml");

var placeholder = "@rx-xhtml";

xDoc.Root.Element("xhtml").Value = placeholder;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc.Root, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

var json_final =json
    .Replace(string.Format(@"""{0}""",placeholder), escaped_xhtml);

json_final.Dump("json with escaped xhtml");

var jDoc = JObject.Parse(json_final);

escaped_xhtml = (string)jDoc["root"]["xhtml"];
escaped_xhtml.Dump("decoded xhtml");
```

It may be reasonable to assume that JSON.NET already has, say, the equivalent of my `getXhtml()` routine. JSON.NET has so many great features I am concerned that I might be missing out.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Does your current code work, or is there a problem?  Are you just looking for `node => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(node.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml })`?

Comment: @dbc Can you write a routine that is simpler, less complicated than the one I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  It produces the same result for `json_final`:

```
        // Parse the XML
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        // Extract the "div" element.
        var div = xDoc.Root.Element("xhtml").Element("div");
        div.Remove();

        // Convert the remainder to a JObject.
        var jDoc = JObject.FromObject(xDoc.Root, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new XmlNodeConverter() } }));

        // Store the Div element as a string literal.
        jDoc["root"]["xhtml"] = div.ToString();

        // Stringify the JSON using StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
        var json_final = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jDoc, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented, StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });
```

It eliminates the string replacement and the `getXhtml` delegate.  Note that `StringEscapeHandling` applies during the *final* conversion to string, not to intermediate conversions to `Joken` (where string literals are not escaped).

Even simpler still, replace the `<Div>` element with a corresponding XML string literal before converting to JSON:

```
        // Parse the XML
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        // Replace the DIV element with its XML string literal value
        var div = xDoc.Root.Element("xhtml").Element("div");
        div.Remove();
        xDoc.Root.Element("xhtml").Value = div.ToString();

        // Convert to JSON using StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
        var json_final = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xDoc, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new XmlNodeConverter() }, Formatting = Formatting.Indented, StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });
```